# ¿Cómo hacer que mis imagenes sean responsive desing, es decir que se adapten a una pantalla de celular sea esta horizontal o vertical?

Tags: html, css

Esta es mi página web https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/ y aqui está un ejemplo del tamaño de las imagenes https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/paginas%20principales/traducir%20texto.html https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/paginas%20principales/enviar%20mensaje%20masivo.html las imagenes son entre 700 y 800 pixeles y más pequeñas. Me pueden dar en codigo css para que queden adaptable a la pantalla y para que también permita hacer zoom a las imagenes

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido marcada como de muy baja calidad por la comunidad. Lee [ask] y edita la pregunta para añadir más información: añade el código en la propia pregunta, lo que hayas intentado, los errores/dificultades que te estés encontrando...

Answer (score 1):

Lo que preguntas es muy complejo, como alternativa, te sugiero que uses width: 100% en las imágenes para que ocupen todo el ancho de la pantalla sea cual sea el ancho de ésta.
Hay imagenes cuyo tamaño esta bien en computadora y que se ve mas pequeñas pero en celulares o en tabletas ocupan un poco mas del 100%, ¿serviria poner algo asi:? o porfavor diganme algo similar, vean esta página para que sepan a lo que me refiero https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/paginas%20principales/acceso%20incognito.html

```css
@media (max-width: XXXpx){
  .modal-ancho{ 
    width: 90%;
  }
```

Comment: eso lo pongo en el documento html o en css?, porque en html <img src: ""> se le puede  agregar el ancho

Comment: Si, lo puedes poner en el tag width de la propia imagen, el resultado no es el que pides, pero se verá mejor hasta que encuentres otra cosa.

Comment: eso de tag with te refieres a html?

Comment: Lo puedes poner de las dos formas, 3 en realidad: en la imagen en el html con width="100%" en el css con una clase o objeto: img { ... } o en un estilo en la propia imagen: <img src='' style='width:100%'>

Comment: y al girar al celular sea que este de modo horizontal y vertical se adaptará si le pongo en html el with?

Comment: En principio si, así es

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices **%**. Por ejemplo:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: eso significa que le tengo que añadir una clase a todas las imagenes insertadas en los tutoriales, porque también tengo estas imagenes pequeñas a las que no me interesa hacerles nada porque salen bien https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/home.html#

Comment: En ese caso, es lo mismo pero delante de img pones tu clase, por ejemplo: .res.img { y luego en tus imágenes a escalar les pones tu clase: <img class='res'...

Comment: y que pasa si lo pongo asi img.res? y al girar el celular la imagen se adaptara a los dos anchos del celular?

Comment: si, es correcto

Comment: Hay 2 posibilidades: 1) Que le pongas una clase a las imágenes de los tutoriales y darle los estilos a esa clase. 2) Que incluyas un archivo de CSS solamente en la página de tutoriales y dentro de ese archivo CSS incluyes los estilos que escribí en la respuesta.

Comment: Sin embargo, te recomendaría la primera opción ya que tendrás más control sobre los estilos de los elementos.

Comment: Puedes ver un ejemplo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/5newew6m/

Comment: entendí amigo, seria la segunda posibilidad

Comment: y si le pongo with en html de 100% a todas las imagenes de tutoriales, al girar el celular si saldrian?

Comment: @AlexandraLoor, te iba a responder, pero fue catalogada como pregunta demasiado amplia por no especificar al detalle lo que quieres hacer. Pero **te recomiendo NO colocarlo en el html** así `<img style="width: 100%">`, sino que en tu css agregues una clase con esa propiedad así: `.img-rd` o `.imagen-fullancho` (el nombre es indiferente), con las propiedades `{width: 100%; height: auto;}`. Y en el html, le agregas esa clase `<img class="img-rd"/>` solo a aquellas imagenes que siempre quieres que ocupen el 100% del dispositivo, ya sea en vertical u horizontal.

Comment: lo quiero solo para celulares que a 800 px las imagenes se vean a un 100% seria algo así @media (max-width: XXXpx){
  .modal-ancho{ 
    width: 90%;
  }